# Xml without root deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, xml, deserialization

I have XML that looks like

```
 <root>
<LogEntry>
    <Data1> </Data1>
    <Data2> </Data2>
</LogEntry>
<LogEntry>
    <Data1> </Data1>
    <Data2> </Data2>
</LogEntry>
 </root>
```

And my class looks like

```
[XmlRoot("Root")]
public class LogEntries
{
    [XmlElement("LogEntry")]
    public List<ClientLogEntry> Entries { get; set; }

    public ClientLogEntries()
    {
        Entries = new List<ClientLogEntry>();
    }
}
```

where ClientLogEntry has properties that are inside LogEntry node.

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LogEntries));
var entries= (LogEntries)serializer.Deserialize(this.TaskDefinition.XmlStream);
```

It says 
          `<root xmlns=''> was not expected.` Any idea what to change?

Comment: The XML that you show here is invalid. It has not a single root entry.

Comment: XML without a root node is technically not XML.  It's a requirement

Comment: Well, you could prepend / append some default XML tags to the stream to create valid XML.

Comment: Yea, that's what I'm trying now

Comment: @Sjips I changed my xml and code but it's still not parsing. It says {"<root xmlns=''> was not expected."}

Comment: And when `[XmlRoot("Root")]` is changed to `[XmlRoot("root")]`? Probably case sensitive. How does the XML look like when you serialize an existing object?